# Database table update using single mysql query

Tags: mysql

[image]

I need a single update query to update the gender in a table - swap 'F' with 'M' and 'M' with 'F'.

Answer (score 4):

Many ways to do this.

One way is using [`case when ...`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) (assuming no `NULL`s or other gender values):

```
update yourtable set gender = (case when gender ='F' then 'M' else 'F' end);
```

Comment: You can add `where gender in ('F','M')` to be safe.